# Writing Regex for Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery

I want to write the regex for a selector in Jquery.
  I have a component having id as `r1:0:newPincode098SelState::content` in which `newPincode098SelState` is common the other part will vary for the components in different
 pages. I want to call .On() function for all the components which contains above string.

So far I have tried `$("input:contains('newPincode098SelState')")` but that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try - [attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("input[id*='newPincode098SelState']")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:regex(attributeName, yourRegexp)")
```